# Is it okay to extract a reference to the "current" value in React.useRef

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Does this cause any unintended side effects and does it deviate from best practices?

```js
var ref = React.useRef(new Obj()).current
// Code using ref
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it okay to extract a reference to the "current" value in React.useRef

tl;dr - Yes, it's okey, but little bit pointless, because you are loosing ability to update it's value.

Of course **you can** update it, but it the fact - the `ref` will not be updated - it will be overwritten. Basically just like you have never used `useRef`. It will become equivalent to `let ref = new Obj();` - and it will be a **different** object with every re-render. `useRef` ensures you that you will get the same `ref` object with every re-render. `let ref` - doesn't.

```
var ref = React.useRef(new Obj());
ref.current = newObj2; // you are able to update it.
                       // the value of ref over re-renders will now equal newObj2

var ref = React.useRef(new Obj()).current;
ref = newObj2; // you are overwriting whole ref
               // it will not be the useRef object anymore
               // all the benefits of using useRef are now gone
```

Conclusion: `var ref = React.useRef(new Obj()).current;` is basically a `read-only` variable.

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified that I'm using useRef to hold a *mutable* object that lasts for the lifetime of the component. For my use case is this still bad practice?

Comment: @RillianGrant Definitely.

Comment: What's the best way to avoid having to put ".current" every time you want to access the object?

Comment: @RillianGrant Just create a new variable. `const ref = useRef();` and `const refValue = ref.current;`